# Why is this graphics component not working?

Tags: java, paintcomponent

I am trying to draw a rectangle in the class "Graphics", but for some reason the rectangle does not appear, but the program returns no errors. I have never experience issues such as this before so I am rather confused.

Main()

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Main
{

    public Main()
    {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        Sound soundCall = new Sound();
        Graphics graphicsCall = new Graphics();

        final JPanel container = new JPanel();

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(container);
        window.setSize(600, 400);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Main();
            }
        });

    }
```

Graphics()

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Graphics extends JPanel
{

    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g)
    { 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawRect(500, 500, 500, 500);
    }

}
```

EDIT FOR HOVERCRAFT

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;


public class Main
{

    public Main()
    {
        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        Sound soundCall = new Sound();
        Draw drawCall = new Draw();

        final JPanel container = new JPanel();

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.getContentPane().add(drawCall);
        window.setSize(600, 400);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                new Main();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Through adding this `window.getContentPane().add(drawCall);` asks me to change `drawCall` to a Component

EDIT 2:

```
public class Draw 
{

    public class Graphics extends JPanel
    {

        public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g)
        { 
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        }

    }


}
```

ERROR
`The method add(Component) in the type Container is not applicable for the arguments (Draw)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You add your graphicsCall variable to nothing, and so it will not be displayed. Solution: add it to a container such as that JPanel that you just created, or perhaps directly to the JFrame's contentPane.

i.e., change this:

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame();

    Sound soundCall = new Sound();
    Graphics graphicsCall = new Graphics();

    final JPanel container = new JPanel();

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.getContentPane().add(container);
```

to this:

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame();

    Sound soundCall = new Sound();
    Graphics graphicsCall = new Graphics();

    // final JPanel container = new JPanel();

    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.getContentPane().add(soundCall);
```

As an aside, you will want to re-name that class from Graphics to something else, or else you risk confusing yourself or your compiler since there already exists a critical Java class with that name.

Also, avoid using `setSize(...)`. Better to have your drawing JPanel override `getPreferredSize()` and to call `pack()` on your JFrame.

---

**Edit**
As per MadProgrammer's astute observation, you're drawing outside of the bounds of your component.

---

**Edit 2**
Regarding your latest code, this:

```
public class Draw 
{
    public class Graphics extends JPanel
    {
        public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g)
        { 
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
            g.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
        }
    }
}
```

is useless dreck. Why are you needlessly wrapping a class inside of a class? Instead why not simply:

```
public class Draw extends JPanel   {

    public void paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics g)
    { 
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.GRAY);
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
       // return an appropriate Dimension here
    }
}
```

Comment: @HarryKitchener: if you try something and it doesn't work, you will want to show the attempt as an edit to your question and describe your problems with your new code. Also see edit to answer.

Comment: The OP is painting the rectangle beyond the visible bounds of component; `g.drawRect(500, 500, 500, 500);`.  Suggest something like  `g.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);` as primary test, I'd also recommend `g.setColor(Color.RED);` over `g.setColor(Color.GRAY);` as this might be the color of the background of the panel, just in case...

Comment: @MadProgrammer: You are of course correct. That should be an answer.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You've already covered the rest, just need that added to finalise it ;)

Comment: I have done that, silly mistake by me. But now if you see the above edit, I am getting an error under `.add`

Comment: @HarryKitchener: so that obviously tells you that `Draw` does not extend JPanel or any Swing component, right?

Comment: Huh? Sorry, I'm confused I am extending Draw as a JPanel, but even when removing this it still returns the same error.

Comment: @HarryKitchener: Show your minimal Draw class code and the actual full error message that this code generates.

Comment: @HarryKitchener: Reviewed and my answer edited. You're now creating bat chit crazy code. Why?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea xD. I removed it and it is now fixed. I'm fairly tired tonight, sorry for idiocy! Thanks.